Access Violation trying to use a getter to a private variable?
I am trying to use a private variable of a class to make an SDL window. To create a window from the private variable, I am trying to use getters and setters. However, I am getting this error:

Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBF93852D7 (SDL2.dll) in ShootemUp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000100000008.

How do I fix this?
Here is my code:
#include "common.h"

void Init() {
    int windowFlag, rendererFlag;
    rendererFlag = SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED;
    windowFlag = 0;

    App application;

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        std::cout << "Couldn't intialize SDL! Error:" << SDL_GetError;
        exit(-1);
    }
    else {

        SDL_Window* window = NULL;
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("Shoot em' up", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        application.setWindow(window);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        if (!application.getWindow()) {
            std::cout << "Window not intialized! Error:" << SDL_GetError;
            exit(-1);
        }

        SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "linear");
        
        SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;
        renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(application.getWindow(), -1, rendererFlag);
        application.setRenderer(renderer);
        if (!application.getRenderer()) {
            std::cout << "Renderer not intialized! Error:" << SDL_Error;
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
}

I am getting the error on this line:
renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(application.getWindow(), -1, rendererFlag);

where I tried to create a renderer using the private window variable.
This is the file with the getters and setters:
#include "Common.h"

void App::setWindow(SDL_Window* window) {
    this->window = window;
}

void App::setRenderer(SDL_Renderer* renderer) {
    this->renderer = renderer;
}

SDL_Window* App::getWindow() {
    return window;
}

SDL_Renderer* App::getRenderer() {
    return renderer;
}


My question is why to you destroy the window immediately after creating it SDL_DestroyWindow(window);. I don't know SDL very well, but that seems like a mistake to me.

@user4581301 you mean nullptr don't you ;)

@user4581301 "After window = SDL_CreateWindow(...); and similar functions, test that the function succeeded" - that is exactly what this code is doing with its if checks. The problem is just that the call to SDL_DestroyWindow() is in the wrong place and thus invalidates the check.

@PepijnKramer Not in this case. It's a C API. You might handle it with nullptr, but it's still returning NULL

@RemyLebeau I missed those. The intervening code disrupted the brain-flow.

You are destroying the SDL_Window object after storing a pointer to it in your application object, thus leaving application holding a dangling pointer, which App::getWindow() then returns later when you try to call SDL_CreateRenderer():
window = SDL_CreateWindow(...);
application.setWindow(window); // <-- sets App::window, OK here so far
SDL_DestroyWindow(window); // <-- now App::window is dangling!
if (!application.getWindow()) { // <-- evaluates as FALSE!
    std::cout << "Window not intialized! Error:" << SDL_GetError;
    exit(-1);
}
...
renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(application.getWindow(), ...); // <-- AV using invalid App::window!

The SDL_Window object is no longer valid when you pass it to SDL_CreateRenderer(), which is Undefined Behavior, and in this case happens to result in an Access Violation error.
Your if (!application.getWindow()) check can't detect this condition, since the SDL_Window* pointer being stored inside the application object is not NULL/nullptr, it is still pointing at the memory you destroyed. An if statement evaluates a pointer as false only for NULL/nullptr, and as true for any other value.  Likewise, operator! evaluates a pointer as true only for NULL/nullptr, and as false for any other value.
To avoid this, you would have to call application.setWindow(nullptr) after calling SDL_DestroyWindow(), so the if check will then evaluate as true, eg:
...
application.setWindow(window);
SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
application.setWindow(nullptr);
if (!application.getWindow()) { // <-- evaluates as TRUE now!
    ...
}
...

Clearly, that is not your real intent.  So, the fix is to simply NOT destroy the SDL_Window object while something is still using it!  The call to SDL_DestroyWindow() (and SDL_DestroyRenderer(), which is missing in this code) needs to be done later in the code, after the application object is finished using the SDL_Window (and SDL_Renderer), such as in the App::~App() destructor (or at least after the application object is destroyed).

After removing the delete part, it worked, thanks for that. However, I created window as a temporary variable to pass its value to the setter. Once I have passed the value, why do I still need that variable as it has already severed its purpose?

@VaidikKhatri I didn't say you need to keep the window variable, only the SDL_Window object that it referred to. I updated my answer to make this clearer.

@VaidikKhatri The way to restrict the variable to the scope where you need it is to use some extra {} to bracket the declaration and the area of code where you want the variable to exist. Like this { SDL_Window* window = NULL; window = SDL_CreateWindow("Shoot em' up", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN); application.setWindow(window); } As already mentioned the lifetime of the variable and the lifetime of the window it refers to are two different things.
